# Getting HttpContext in a task

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, task

I am loosing the HttpContext in method called using a task. Googling seem to suggest this code should work. Any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

```
    void ThisMethodIsCalledFromASPNet()
    {
        var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;   // Here I am getting valid context

        Task.Factory.StartNew( () => DoSomething(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, 
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;   // Here I am getting null
    }
```

Comment: What if you changed `DoSomething` to accept an `HttpContext` as a parameter?

Comment: sure but I am hoping for some better ways

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a better way than that.

Comment: @johnsmith only in the thread who handles a request you can get the context. In any other thread you get null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the `HttpContext`:

```
void ThisMethodIsCalledFromASPNet()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew( 
        ctx => DoSomething((HttpContext)ctx),
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current,
        CancellationToken.None, 
        TaskCreationOptions.None, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

void DoSomething(HttpContext ctx)
{
    // ctx is your HttpContext
}
```